# Calculating Total ins JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I had this question posted earlier but it was a bit different. I am taking a new approach and it doesnt seem to be working. I was wondering if I could get some help with figuring out where I am going wrong. The aim of this is to calculate while they are typing in values or as soon as they remove the focus from the text box

ASP:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmount1" CssClass="narrow"  text="0.00"  ClientIDMode="Static" class="PAmount"  /> 
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmount2" CssClass="narrow"  text="0.00"  ClientIDMode="Static" class="PAmount"  /> 
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmount3" CssClass="narrow"  text="0.00"  ClientIDMode="Static" class="PAmount"  /> 
  <asp:Literal ID="ltlGTotal" runat="server" Text="0.00" ></asp:Literal>
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTotalCost" CssClass="narrow"/>
```

JS:

```
  $('.PAmount').keyup(function () { 
    var total;
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this).length; ++i) {
        total += parseInt($(this)[i].val());
    }
    $('#ltlGTotal').val(total);
    $('#txtTotalCost').val(total);
});
```

Comment: @theshadowmonkey I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommand Total Textbox as editable.

Besides, there is no point of letting user enters value into Total.

For example, 1+2+3=8 (total will not be correct).

**FYI**: You cannot have both `CssClass="narrow"` and `class="PAmount"`; it is not a proper format.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmount1" CssClass="narrow" 
  Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmount2" CssClass="narrow" 
  Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmount3" CssClass="narrow" 
  Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:Label ID="ltlGTotal" runat="server" Text="0.00" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTotalCost" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"/>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ltlGTotal').html($('#txtTotalCost').val());

        $('.narrow').keyup(calculate);

        $('.total').keyup(calculate);

        function calculate() {
            var total = 0;
            $('.narrow').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                    total += parseInt($(this).val());
                }
            });
            $('#ltlGTotal').html(total);
            $('#txtTotalCost').val(total);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Win....the problem with using the .narrow is that on the actual form i have other boxes with that same class.

Comment: ill just create another class for those boxes

Comment: It works for the textboxes but for some reason the literal isnt changing

Comment: Sorry, I accidenlty removed `ClientIDMode="Static"` for `ltlGTotal`

Comment: I actually declared that at the top of the page after I realised ill be using it basically right through the page. Im still trying to figure out where the hitch could have been

Comment: Well everything except the literal

Comment: It's just like in my answer, the literal needs to be changed to a label and everything should be fine.

Comment: The problem about your original code is - it doesn't loop though each textbox once keyup event is fired. I'm glad that you figure out. Take care!

Comment: Literal controls just render the text without a wrapping tag, therefore there is nothing for jQuery to reference, it's undefined. If you change it to a Label, it will render a span tag that wraps the text allowing jQuery to reference it and then change the contents via the `.text()` method, as in my answer

Comment: I got that going. Ok so now i realise that I am facing another issue. I have a couple drop downs that are autopostback and as soon as it posts back both the ltlGTotal and the txtTotalCost go blank, but the amounts are still filled. Any suggestions on how to deal with that?

Comment: I updated the code. You need `$('#ltlGTotal').html($('#txtTotalCost').val());` at the page load if you want to persist the information between post back.

Comment: what do i add to the page load to persist information btween postbacks?

Comment: What I do is create a `loadEvents()` function and inside of that function I do whatever binding that I want persisted and then put this at the bottom of my js: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(loadEvents);`. That will fire at the end of the request after everything has loaded and is accessible.

Comment: Oh I added that. What Would i do for the '#txtTotalCost', that one goes blank also

Comment: You would do like my answer shows. It has the `calculateTotal()` function, and you would just call that from within the `loadEvents()` function.

Comment: @Robertpurpose You do not need `loadEvents` if you place `$('#ltlGTotal').html($('#txtTotalCost').val());` inside document.ready (Unless you use Ajax). As far as I tested, `txtTotalCost` doesn't goes blank because `TextBox` control has `ViewState` (as long as you don't' turn off `ViewState`intentionally).

Comment: Ok I am not sure what happened but. Now on the postback they both go blank

Comment: All I know is that we've *basically* turned this answer into what my answer was almost 2 hours ago, lol, no offense.

Comment: @Robertpurpose - Please make sure one of your server code does not wipe out `txtTotalCost`'s value when posting back. If it still doesn't work, you want to create a sample test project and debug your code in it. Good luck!

Comment: @Robertpurpose - No problemo!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
var $amountBoxes = $(":text.PAmount"),
    $grandTotal = $("#ltlGTotal"),
    $totalCost = $("#txtTotalCost");

$amountBoxes.on("keyup change", calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal()
{
    var total = 0;
    $amountBoxes.each(function () 
    {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $grandTotal.text(total.toString());
    $totalCost.val(total.toString());
};
```

***[Click here to view a working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd5wG/)***

Comment: @Robertpurpose - What about it doesn't work exactly? It works in the fiddle demo. You may have to adjust the selectors for the total fields due to .NET pre-pending the id's with `ctl00_`.

Comment: my Ids are static. I know most times i test things in JFiddle and pass it over to the real system and it has issues. I am still trying to figure out where the problem is because I am confident this is an amazing solution to my question

Comment: @Robertpurpose - Yea, that's confusing. Try commenting out the literal control parts, `$grandTotal = $("#ltlGTotal"),` and `$grandTotal.text(total.toString());`. Maybe that's what's screwing things up.

Comment: @Robertpurpose - I was confused at what the difference between your grand total literal control and the total cost textbox were to begin with.

Comment: oh on my actual form. There are drop downs above each amount box and then there is a grand total displayed in the literal. Then in the total textbox is just a total that would be displayed in the credit card section of my form

Comment: @Robertpurpose - Hmm, I'm thinking it's the literal control. I think you should change the literal control to a label control, as the latter actually renders a `<span />` tag that allows jQuery to access. I'm pretty sure the literal control just renders text.

Comment: @Robertpurpose - You could also hit F12 or whatever your browser's developer tools are to see if the js is erroring out somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$('.PAmount').keyup(function () {
    var total=0;
    $('.PAmount').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });     
    $('#ltlGTotal').val(total);
    $('#txtTotalCost').val(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change event using the "narrow" css class like this:

```
$('.narrow').change(function () {
  var total;
   for (var i = 0; i < $(this).length; ++i) {
      total += parseInt($(this)[i].val());
   }
   $('#ltlGTotal').val(total);
  $('#txtTotalCost').val(total);
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem with that is, I have other textboxes with the same CssClass name